# How to intercept and redirect EventSource requests to another address in the browser?

Tags: javascript, events, browser, proxy, server-sent-events

1. I am using a library that makes requests using EventSource.
2. I need to intercept these requests and redirect them to another address (localhost:3005).

Comment: By "redirect to localhost:3005" you mean you want the web browser to act like a server and listen to requests on port 3005? I think that is impossible - outside the security model of the browser, but I'm not sure on that. https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-run-a-proxy-server-inside-your-browser-8b96ea2ef1ea was interesting, though I don't think it is describing what you want?

Comment: Thank you for this link https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-run-a-proxy-server-inside-your-browser-8b96ea2ef1ea. I need something similar. 
 In my case, I would like to intercept not only fetch requests but also SSE (Server-Sent Events) requests and redirect them, for example, to a proxy server like localhost:3005.

Comment: The issue is that I'm experiencing CORS blocking on certain URLs in the browser. Additionally, I cannot control these URLs as they are used in some libraries. 
 
In reality, I am using and exploring a new technology called https://webcontainers.io. Webcontainers allows running Node.js in the browser. Webcontainers has a strict COOP/COEP headers policy. Because of this, I need to intercept and redirect certain URLs.